# How can I mark all packages with installed dependents as "Automatically Installed"?

Tags: apt

There are some similar questions, but here is precisely what I would like to achieve and the dots which I am having trouble connecting:

1. Query a list of "Manually Installed" packages (`apt-mark showmanual` works)
2. Check each package for *installed* dependents
3. Mark each such package as "Automatically Installed" (`apt-mark auto <pkg ...>` works)

So I think my command will look something like:

```
apt-mark showmanual | <esoteric apt/bash magic> | apt-mark auto -
```

Would that be correct?

**Related Questions**

1. [How do I find which packages could be set as automatically installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248283/how-do-i-find-which-packages-could-be-set-as-automatically-installed)
2. [Why are almost all packages marked as manually installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12279/why-are-almost-all-packages-marked-as-manually-installed) (See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/livecd-rootfs/+bug/424643/comments/26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Aptitude's `why` command](http://peterstuifzand.nl/2010/11/11/aptitude-why.html):

```
for x in $(apt-mark showmanual)
do
  r="$(echo ${x} | sed -e 's/\([+.]\)/[\1]/g')"
  aptitude why ${x} | egrep -q "^i.* (Pre)?Depends +${r}( |$)" && apt-mark auto ${x}
done
```

Not tested, because it's not something I want to (have to un-)do on my machine.

Comment: The grep above is quite broad. It matches things like: `aptitude why vim` … `p   vim-migemo Depends  vim`. The grep should check for lines starting with "i" and having the actual package looked for after it. I have submitted an edit to this answer.